# Making an array ints and replace the order of number I write

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop

What I try to do, is for example if I write five numbers 1,2,3,4,5 after this it should print 5,4,3,2,1

```
int[] numbers = new int[5];

for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length ; i++)
{
    Console.Write("");

    numbers[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}

for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
{

}
```

Comment: Okay, and your question is what?

Comment: Sort numbers, or iterate through it in reverse order.

Comment: Change your second loop to count backwards to zero. `for(int i=numbers.Length - 1; i>= 0; i--)`

Answer (score 3):

If you need just to print them in a reverse order, but you want to keep them stored as you inserted them, change the second loop like this:

```
for (int i=numbers.Length-1; i >= 0; i--){
    Console.WriteLine(numbers[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can print the array with a reverse loop as in the previous answer, or you can do that in a single line:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", numbers.Reverse()));
```

Comment: Thanks for the revenge downvote